# Why can I not "find all solutions" for a deterministic predicate?

Tags: prolog

I am writing a program to **find all of the squares that a Knight can move to** in a game of chess.

For example: `validKnightMove(X1/Y1, X2/Y2).` where each argument is a co-ordinate pair.

#### What I've done:

- Written the predicate.
- Made it deterministic using cuts.
- Unit-tested it with PL-Unit.

The predicate ***works***, but I cannot query it in a desirable way from the Prolog shell.

#### What I'd like to do:

I would like to make a query that will find all of the valid squares I can move to from a given location. For example, `?- validKnightMove(4/4, X/Y)`, then the shell would search for `X` and `Y` values which satisfy the predicate.

However, when I make the query, it simply returns `false.`, despite having valid solutions.

*Here is some output from the shell to demonstrate the issue:*

```
1 ?- validKnightMove(4/4, 6/3).
true.

2 ?- validKnightMove(4/4, X/Y).
false.
```

#### Here is my code:

This code is admittedly verbose, but should be easy to read.

```
validKnightMove(X1/Y1, X2/Y2) :- % Right 1, Down 2
    onBoard(X2/Y2),
    X2 =:= X1 + 1,
    Y2 =:= Y1 + 2,
    !.

validKnightMove(X1/Y1, X2/Y2) :- % Right 2, Down 1
    onBoard(X2/Y2),
    X2 =:= X1 + 2,
    Y2 =:= Y1 + 1,
    !.

validKnightMove(X1/Y1, X2/Y2) :- % Left 2, Down 1
    onBoard(X2/Y2),
    X2 =:= X1 - 2,
    Y2 =:= Y1 + 1,
    !.

validKnightMove(X1/Y1, X2/Y2) :- % Left 1, Down 2
    onBoard(X2/Y2),
    X2 =:= X1 - 1,
    Y2 =:= Y1 + 2,
    !.

validKnightMove(X1/Y1, X2/Y2) :- % Right 1, Up 2
    onBoard(X2/Y2),
    X2 =:= X1 + 1,
    Y2 =:= Y1 - 2,
    !.

validKnightMove(X1/Y1, X2/Y2) :- % Right 2, Up 1
    onBoard(X2/Y2),
    X2 =:= X1 + 2,
    Y2 =:= Y1 - 1,
    !.

validKnightMove(X1/Y1, X2/Y2) :- % Left 2, Up 1
    onBoard(X2/Y2),
    X2 =:= X1 - 2,
    Y2 =:= Y1 - 1,
    !.

validKnightMove(X1/Y1, X2/Y2) :- % Left 1, Up 2
    onBoard(X2/Y2),
    X2 =:= X1 - 1,
    Y2 =:= Y1 - 2,
    !.

onBoard(X/Y) :-
    between(1, 8, X),
    between(1, 8, Y),
    !.
```

My question is: **Why can't prolog find all the solutions for a deterministic predicate?**

Note: My prolog version is SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 32 bits, Version 6.2.2)

Comment: All the cuts prune your solution tree severely. Even `onBoard(X/Y)` will only yield one solution (`X = 1` and `Y = 1`) due to the cut.

Comment: @lurker Should I remove all the cuts to achieve the desired output?

Comment: I would start with that. I didn't analyze your solution top to bottom, so I don't know if that will be the final solution.

Comment: It works! Removing all of the cuts allows me to achieve the desired behaviour. But does this make my program less efficient? Doing so will give me warnings when running the tests: `Test succeeded with choicepoint`.

Comment: Just removing cuts makes the program more correct. In this case, more correct takes more time because it is generating all the solutions instead of some (or one) of them. Using CL(PFD) instead of `between` and `=:=` might be more efficient. Also, I would think you'd want something like, `validKnightMove1(X1/Y1, X2/Y2) :- onBoard(X2, Y2), validKnightMove(X1/Y1, X2/Y2)` and remove the `onBoard/2` calls in your `validKnightMove/2` predicates.

Comment: @lurker Your help is very much appreciated. I like removing the duplication too.

Comment: They used to distinguish between red and green cuts based on whether the cut affected something observable. I would definitely avoid them as long as possible. Say hi to Kyril for me.